# Update column having certain value to a value with max value on another a column with same id

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

already asked this in another question but criteria changed.

My Table:

```
 ID | NumDate  | Number
-------------------
| 1 | 20150101 | 0x
| 1 | 20140101 | 12345678
| 1 | 20130101 | 12345
| 2 | 20150101 | 0x
| 2 | 20130101 | 0x
| 2 | 20091111 | 242424
| 3 | 20150101 | 88888
| 3 | 20141010 | 88888
| 4 | 20150101 | 0x
| 4 | 20141010 | 0x
| 5 | 20141010 | 0101010
| 5 | 20141010 | 0101010
| 5 | 20141010 | 0x
```

Every '0x' must be updated to a 'Number' with biggest 'NumDate' which is not '0x'.

No updates if there exists no other value than '0x'.

Result needed:

```
ID  | NumDate   | Number
-------------------
| 1 | 20150101 | 12345678      <-- ID = 1, Updated
| 1 | 20140101 | 12345678
| 1 | 20130101 | 12345
| 2 | 20150101 | 242424        <-- ID = 2, Updated
| 2 | 20130101 | 242424        <-- ID = 2, Updated
| 2 | 20091111 | 242424
| 3 | 20150101 | 88888         <- No change on id = 3, '88888' on both rows
| 3 | 20141010 | 88888         <- No change on id = 3, '88888' on both rows
| 4 | 20150101 | 0x            <- No change, there's no *better* 'Number' 
| 4 | 20141010 | 0x            <- No change, there's no *better* 'Number'
| 5 | 20141010 | 0101010
| 5 | 20141010 | 0101010 
| 5 | 20141010 | 0101010       <-- Updated
```

Tried this (thnx [Kaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412923/kaf)):

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ID, Number, Max(NumDate) NumDate
    FROM TEST_03
    WHERE Number <> '0X'
    GROUP BY ID
)
UPDATE ut SET Number = c.Number
FROM TEST_03 ut
    JOIN CTE c ON ut.ID = c.ID
WHERE ut.Number = '0X'
    JOIN CTE c ON ut.ID = c.ID
WHERE ut.Number = '0x'
```

I get:

```
Column 'TEST_03.Number' is invalid in the select list because it is not 
contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

I do see the error in usage of aggregate function. Doesn't fit here?

Now, I don't know how to approach this.
Maybe I should copy 'ID', 'Numdate' and 'Number'  to another table and update using JOIN, to keep it simple? Examples, anyone?

Or perhaps there's a way to make it in existing table?

Any help would be appreciated, 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is different to my answer. [Try my answer to your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439575/update-column-with-certain-value-to-a-column-value-with-same-id/32439842#32439842)

Comment: find the last edit to my answer, that worked fine

Comment: Btw, why the third row value gets updated to 12345678? As per your logic only those rows which have 0x as Number value should be updated.

Comment: True, third row will not be edited. Edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
update t3
set Number = t1.Number
from dbo.test t3 join dbo.test t1 on t3.id = t1.id
join
(
select id, max(numDate) as maxdate
from dbo.test
where number<>'0x'
group by id
) t2
on t1.id = t2.id and t1.NumDate = t2.maxdate
where t3.number = '0x'
```

Comment: Tried this. Did not find '0x' rows. Record Count: 0  and 0 rows affected

Comment: It works at my end with the sample data you provided.

Comment: Made a mistake on Question, Rows 2 and 3 have different 'Number'. Sub-query gives two records for id = 1, maybe that prevents all updates?

Comment: Please see this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9cecc/1 It is the exact sample data and output that you provided.

Comment: Correct. In my real database I have lots of other columns. You think that's why i get result '(0 row(s) affected)' ?

Answer (score 1):

try to add group by number in your CTE and delete the last join
[see the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba851/1)

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT ID, Number, Max(NumDate) NumDate
FROM TEST_03
WHERE Number <> '0X'
GROUP BY ID, Number
)
UPDATE ut SET Number = c.Number
FROM TEST_03 ut
    JOIN CTE c ON ut.ID = c.ID
WHERE ut.Number = '0X'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best solution for this would be using CROSS APPLY:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT t1.Number, t2.Number as NewNumber
    FROM TEST_03 t1
    CROSS APPLY
    (
       SELECT top 1 Number 
       FROM TEST_03
       WHERE
         t1.ID = ID
         and Number <> '0X'
       ORDER BY NumDate DESC
    ) t2
    WHERE t1.Number = '0X'
)
UPDATE CTE
SET Number = NewNumber
```

Comment: Made a mistake on Question, Rows 2 and 3 have different 'Number'. Sub-query gives two records for id = 1, maybe that prevents all updates?

Comment: @Kaptah this will not return 2 rows, it will take 1 Number from the latest date, if the latest date has 2 entries, it will pick ONE arbitrary Number.